# Not displaying the row numbers continuosly while using pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm using pagination in my website but the problem is that it's not displaying the row numbers continuously.

In my web page I am displaying the rows 10 per page. Clicking on the next page it is displaying the row numbers from 1 again. Actually it should start from 11 in the page but it is displaying again as 1.

Controller:

```
function index()
{
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url("index.php/blogs/index");
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->blogs_model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 11;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['records'] = $this->blogs_model->get_blogs($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data['comments'] = $this->blogs_model->getcommentscount($this->uri->segment(3));
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['mainpage'] = 'blogs';
    $data['mode'] = 'all';
    $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_blogs($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->Select('blogs.*');
    $this->db->From('blogs');
    $this->db->where(array('blogs.status' => 1));
    $this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i see your url when you click page 2?

Comment: @MahbubulIslam clicking on the second page the url is showing as like this - http://www.staging.website.com/admin/index.php/blogs/index/11

Comment: Any idea why the problem is occuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done some changes in view its working fine.Here is the latest code for displaying the s.no correctly after clicking on pagination links.

```
<?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">S.No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Blog Title</th>                         
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                <?php $i = $this->uri->segment(3)+0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>
                    <tr>                                                        
                        <td class="align-center"><?php echo $i;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->blog_title;?></td>                     

                    </tr>

                 <?php  } ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="pagination"><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></div>
```

Comment: After 3 days of testing and trying tons of methods, nothing works except yours. But with a small change, because in my case I used `$i = $this->uri->segment(4)+1;`... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems fine. You can change your `Model`'s function like this.

```
function get_blogs($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('blogs');
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $this->db->order_by("date", "DESC");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$config['uri_segment'] = 3;` add this to config before initialization of pagination.

Comment: Ok. Then make sure you have loaded these two properly.
`$this->load->helper("url");`  
`$this->load->library("pagination");`   
Best if you `autoload` them or load them in the `Controller`'s `__construct()` method.

Comment: Yes i have loaded these both url

Comment: Then i am sure the problem is in this line `$page = ($this->uri-> segment(3)) ? $this-> uri->segment(3) : 0;`

Comment: `echo $page; exit` to check

Comment: It is displaying 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153111/discussion-between-mahbubul-islam-and-user6728960).